# mapStateToProps inclusion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

First of all I know a lot of stuff in this code snippet is off, I know. I'm only trying to address the question here.
For some reason my app says that it cannot read property 'todo' of undefined, and highlights `todos: [...state.todos]`.
Am I not importing something that I should be here?

Form.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import uuidv1 from 'uuid';
import { addTodo } from '../actions';
import TodoInput from './todo-input';
import TodoList from './TodoList';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addTodo: todo => dispatch(addTodo(todo))
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  todos: [...state.todos]
})

class ConnectedForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { inputValue} = this.state;
    const id = uuidv1();
    this.props.addTodo({inputValue, id});
    this.setState({inputValue: ''});
  }

  handleToggle (e) {
    const id = parseInt(e.target.id);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      todos: prevState.todos.map(todo => todo.id === id ? {...todo, done: !todo.done} : todo)
    }));
    console.log(e.target);
  }

  render() {
    const { inputValue } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className='form-group'>
          <TodoInput
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          />

          <TodoList />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const Form = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (ConnectedForm);

export default Form;
```

TodoList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
import { removeTodo, toggleComplete } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      removeTodo: id => dispatch(removeTodo(id)),
      toggleComplete: isDone => dispatch(toggleComplete(isDone))
    };
  };

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {todos: [...state.todos]};
};

class List extends Component {
  render() {
    const mappedTodos = this.props.todos.map((todo, index) => (
      <TodoItem 
      todo={todo}
      title={todo.title}
      key={index}
      removeHandler={this.props.removeTodo}
      toggleComplete={this.props.toggleComplete}
      />
    ));
    return (
      mappedTodos
    );
  }
}

const TodoList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (List)
export default TodoList;
```

Reducers

```
import { ADD_TODO, REMOVE_TODO, TOGGLE_COMPLETE } from '../constants/action-types'; 
import uuidv1 from 'uuid';

const initialState = {
  todos: []
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
    return {
        ...state,
        todos: [...state.todos,
          {
            title: action.payload.inputValue,
            id: uuidv1(),
            createdAt: Date(),
            priority: '',
            deadline: '',
            isComplete: false
          }]
    }

    case REMOVE_TODO:
    return {
      ...state,
      todos: [...state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id  !== action.payload)]
    }

    case TOGGLE_COMPLETE: 
    return (
      console.log(action.payload)
    )

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Where is the connected component code?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. The code you posted doesn't contain `todo` property.

Comment: Ok that should be everything needed. I was trying to keep it a small post, was just asking if I should be importing a store or something as a general question.

Comment: where it's says the undefined is? which line \ code section \ function???

Comment: Says in the question
"For some reason my app says that it cannot read property 'todo' of undefined, and highlights todos: [...state.todos]." It's in the Form.js in `mapStateToProps`

Comment: Can anyone help?